# Split row by two columns and keep other columns the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a sample like below:

```
col1  col2  Name_1  Gender_1   Age_1  I#2_Name  I#2_Gender   I#2_Age   Unique_Col
A1      50     Amy         F    20         NaN         NaN       NaN       Key_01
A2      20    Judy         F    35        Andy           M        37       Key_02
A3      10   James         M    45       Alice           F        45       Key_03
A4     150     Sam         M    23         NaN         NaN       NaN       Key_04  
A5     200   Annie         F    40        John         NaN       NaN       Key_05
```

I want to split the dataframe from one rows to two rows if there are second name.

```
col1  col2  Name_new  Gender_new   Age_new        Unique_Col
A1      50     Amy         F            20         Key_01_N1
A2      20    Judy         F            35         Key_02_N1
A2      20    Andy         M            37         Key_02_N2
A3      10   James         M            45         Key_03_N1
A3      10   Alice         F            45         Key_03_N2
A4     150     Sam         M            23         Key_04_N1  
A5     200   Annie         F            40         Key_05_N1 
A5     200    John       NaN           NaN         Key_05_N2
```

Sometimes, there are missing value in second gender and age.
Any idea?

Comment: In the first table, `John` doesn't have an `Age_2` or `Gender_2`.

Comment: Sometimes, there are missing value in second gender and age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to reshape the data:

```
(df.pivot_longer(index = ['col1', 'col2', 'Unique_Col'], 
                 names_to = ['Name_new', 'Gender_new', 'Age_new'],  
                 names_pattern = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age'],
                 sort_by_appearance = True)
)
 
  col1  col2 Unique_Col Name_new Gender_new  Age_new
0   A1    50     Key_01      Amy          F     20.0
1   A1    50     Key_01      NaN        NaN      NaN
2   A2    20     Key_02     Judy          F     35.0
3   A2    20     Key_02     Andy          M     37.0
4   A3    10     Key_03    James          M     45.0
5   A3    10     Key_03    Alice          F     45.0
6   A4   150     Key_04      Sam          M     23.0
7   A4   150     Key_04      NaN        NaN      NaN
8   A5   200     Key_05    Annie          F     40.0
9   A5   200     Key_05     John        NaN      NaN
```

In the code above, you pass a list of new column names to `names_to`. For each new column name, you pass a pattern(regular expression) to `names_pattern`. So, for `Names_new`, the function will search for any column that contains `Name` and pull all the data into that column, same goes for `Gender_new` and `Age_new`.

You could also stick to pandas only and use [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html); first reorder the columns so that `Gender`, `Name`, and `Age` are at the front:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns = lambda col: "_".join(col.split("_")[::-1]) 
                              if "#" in col else col)
new_df
  col1  col2 Name_1 Gender_1  Age_1 Name_I#2 Gender_I#2  Age_I#2 Unique_Col
0   A1    50    Amy        F     20      NaN        NaN      NaN     Key_01
1   A2    20   Judy        F     35     Andy          M     37.0     Key_02
2   A3    10  James        M     45    Alice          F     45.0     Key_03
3   A4   150    Sam        M     23      NaN        NaN      NaN     Key_04
4   A5   200  Annie        F     40     John        NaN      NaN     Key_05
```

Let's reshape:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(new_df, 
                 stubnames = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age'], 
                 i = ['col1', 'col2', 'Unique_Col'], 
                 j = 'suffix', 
                 sep = "_", 
                 suffix = ".+")
   .droplevel("suffix")
   .reset_index()
)



  col1  col2 Unique_Col   Name Gender   Age
0   A1    50     Key_01    Amy      F  20.0
1   A1    50     Key_01    NaN    NaN   NaN
2   A2    20     Key_02   Judy      F  35.0
3   A2    20     Key_02   Andy      M  37.0
4   A3    10     Key_03  James      M  45.0
5   A3    10     Key_03  Alice      F  45.0
6   A4   150     Key_04    Sam      M  23.0
7   A4   150     Key_04    NaN    NaN   NaN
8   A5   200     Key_05  Annie      F  40.0
9   A5   200     Key_05   John    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: If my name, gender, and age columns do not have the same patterns. How can I do that? Also, if there are many columns in the dataframe, is there any efficient way to pass to `index`?

Comment: kindly share an example for that, with expected output @PeterChen

Comment: quick question: is it possible to also manipulate column `Unique_Col` to be `Key_02_N1` and `Key_02_N2`?

Comment: Not sure I understand @PeterChen, could you explain better? An example would help

Comment: Ahhh... That's like a whole new question. Do you mind creating a new question and ping me; I (and others in the community) will attempt to solve it. Also, please explain the logic for N1 and N2 suffix in the `Unique_Col`

Answer (score 1):

Create two dateframes with columns `cols1` and `cols2`(see the values in code).

In the second dataframe, drop the values where all the `Name_x`, `Gender_x`, `Age_x` are `nan`, which means second name doesn't exist.
Rename `Name_x`, `Gender_x`, `Age_x` to `Name_new`, `Gender_new`, `Age_new` in both the dataframes.

Then use `pd.concat` to concat the dateframes  vertically.

Use:

```
cols1 = ['col1', 'col2', 'Name_1', 'Gender_1', 'Age_1', 'Unique_Col']
cols2 = ['col1', 'col2', 'Name', 'Gender_2', 'Age_2', 'Unique_Col']

def rename_col(x):
   return x.split("_")[0] + "_new" if '_' in x else x

df1 = df[cols1].rename(rename_col, axis = 'columns')
df2 = (df[cols2]
          .dropna(subset = ['Name_2', 'Gender_2', 'Age_2'], how = 'all')
          .rename(rename_col, axis = 'columns'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  col1  col2 Name_new Gender_new  Age_new Unique_new
0   A1    50      Amy          F     20.0     Key_01
1   A2    20     Judy          F     35.0     Key_02
1   A2    20     Andy          M     37.0     Key_02
2   A3    10    James          M     45.0     Key_03
2   A3    10    Alice          F     45.0     Key_03
3   A4   150      Sam          M     23.0     Key_04
4   A5   200    Annie          F     40.0     Key_05
4   A5   200     John        NaN      NaN     Key_05
```

---

If your gender and name do not have same patterns then use a dictionary mapping to rename:

```
cols1 = ['col1', 'col2', 'Name_1', 'Gender_1', 'Age_1', 'Unique_Col']
cols2 = ['col1', 'col2', 'I#2_Name', 'I#2_Gender', 'I#2_Age', 'Unique_Col']

new_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'Name_New', 'Gender_New', 'Age_New', 'Unique_Col']

df1 = df[cols1].rename(dict(zip(cols1, new_cols)), axis = 'columns')
df2 = (df[cols2]
          .dropna(subset = cols2[2:5], how = 'all')
          .rename(dict(zip(cols2, new_cols)), axis = 'columns'))

out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by = ['col1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try the pandas melt function. Something like

`pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Name_1','Name_2'])`

Comment: Did you check the output?